# discord.py way to use the bot in a new thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, python-multithreading, discord.py

I'm making my discord.py bot, and I want a way to send custom messages. I tried using `on_message` but kept having error about threading.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
        print(f'{bot.user.name} is now on Discord!')
        #Here I want a loop that asks for input, then, if it gets it, the bot sends it.
```

I've tried using `Thread`'s, but I can't `await` in a thread.

```py
#I want to do somthing like:
channel = bot.get_channel(my_channel_id)
while True:
    msg = input("Bot: ")
    await channel.send(msg)
```

Thanks for all your answers!

---

EDIT:
I'm having trouble getting your solutions to work, and I'm pretty sure it's my fault. Is there any way for the bot to run normally, but while it does, there is a loop asking for input and sending it to discord as the bot when it gets it.

Like a *working* version of this?:

```py
c = bot.get_channel(my_channel_id)
while True:
    message = input("Bot: ")
    await c.send(message)
```

Comment: You have a fundamental understanding problem what async/await does. Creating a new `Thread` (resources are not shared between threads) using blocking calls like `input()` (discord py is already asynchron and this halts the entire program) etc breaks the discord.py library.
What you are asking for is not possible. Take a few steps back and try to learn the technologies you are using.

Comment: @TinNguyen Creating a new thread in an async program won't break it (Creating is cheap and don't block long). There are cases it's needed but usually you don't want to mix threads and async.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK There is no async equivalent of `input()` in standard library. There are some workarounds for it, here is my suggestion that I think is the cleanest:

Fire up a thread when your program starts that you can run the blocking `input()` call in it. I used an executor because asyncio has a handy function to communicate with executor of any kind. Then from async code schedule a new job in executor and wait for it.

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        line = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, input)
        print('Got text:', line)


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
asyncio.run(main())
```